# Lua - xterm 256 colors gradient scripting

Tags: colors, lua, gradient, 256color

This has been bothering me for a bit, and I'm not sure there is an answer out there. I know there are modules such as Love2D that accomplish gradients, which I'm guessing uses RGB coloring. However, I'm needing to find something quite similar using xterm 256 colors, but I cannot seem to find a gradient map anywhere to assist with this.

My guess is that I'll have to create a "nearest to RGB color" and create a gradient from that, matching the corresponding RBG to the nearest xterm match, but to be quite honest, I don't even know where to begin with this. I know there's a "convert xterm to RGB hex" script in Python (located [here](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/719710)), but as I don't know Python, I don't know how to convert that to Lua.

Ultimately, what I want to do is be able to turn text into a rainbow gradient, more or less. I currently have a function to return xterm colors, but it's completely random, and the output can be a bit harsh to read. Here's what I have for that code. The `@x` stands for "convert to xterm color", and it is followed by a three digit code (001 to 255), followed by the text.

```
function rainbow(text)
    local rtext = ""
    local xcolor = 1
    local sbyte = 1
    for i = 1, #text do
        math.randomseed(os.time() * xcolor * sbyte)
        sbyte = string.byte(i)
        xcolor = math.random(1, 255)
        rtext = rtext .. "@x" .. string.rep("0", 3 - string.len(xcolor)) .. xcolor .. text:sub(i,i)
    end
    return rtext
end
```

So, for example, `print(rainbow("Test"))` would result in:

`@x211T@x069e@x154s@x177t`

Obviously, this is not a gradient, and is not what I want to end up with. Is what I want possible, or is it a lost cause?

**Edit**
I know the limitiations of 256 colors, and I know there's not a whole lot of wiggle room. As was pointed out in the comment, there'd be a lot of the same color matching, so I'd get a string of the same colors. That's fine with me, really. No matter how many actual transitions it makes, I'd like for it to closely simulate a gradient.

What would be nice is if I were able to at least create color groups properly without having to poll the charts. What I may wind up having to do, I guess, is create a table of "compatible colors schemes" and work with that, unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: Firstly, you probably don't have enough shades of any one hue to properly map an RGB gradient to an arbitrary 256 color palette. If you could define your own palette at run time then you may get away with it, but it could potentially take a lot of colors. Secondly, even with 256 colors used for a single gradient, you likely will end up with serious banding. This is because many RGB colors will map to the same color in your new palette. So on top of mapping colors, you need to do dithering too.

Comment: Right, I am aware of the limitations of 256 colors, but ultimately, I guess I just want something to simulate it as closely as possible. I suppose at the very least, I would like it to randomize the first xterm value, then gradually increase/decrease in shading based off it. I know it's quite a long shot, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `nearest_term256_color_index` function:

```
local abs, min, max, floor = math.abs, math.min, math.max, math.floor
local levels = {[0] = 0x00, 0x5f, 0x87, 0xaf, 0xd7, 0xff}

local function index_0_5(value) -- value = color component 0..255
   return floor(max((value - 35) / 40, value / 58))
end

local function nearest_16_231(r, g, b)   -- r, g, b = 0..255
   -- returns color_index_from_16_to_231, appr_r, appr_g, appr_b
   r, g, b = index_0_5(r), index_0_5(g), index_0_5(b)
   return 16 + 36 * r + 6 * g + b, levels[r], levels[g], levels[b]
end

local function nearest_232_255(r, g, b)  -- r, g, b = 0..255
   local gray = (3 * r + 10 * g + b) / 14
   -- this is a rational approximation for well-known formula
   -- gray = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
   local index = min(23, max(0, floor((gray - 3) / 10)))
   gray = 8 + index * 10
   return 232 + index, gray, gray, gray
end

local function color_distance(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2)
   return abs(r1 - r2) + abs(g1 - g2) + abs(b1 - b2)
end

local function nearest_term256_color_index(r, g, b)   -- r, g, b = 0..255
   local idx1, r1, g1, b1 = nearest_16_231(r, g, b)
   local idx2, r2, g2, b2 = nearest_232_255(r, g, b)
   local dist1 = color_distance(r, g, b, r1, g1, b1)
   local dist2 = color_distance(r, g, b, r2, g2, b2)
   return dist1 < dist2 and idx1 or idx2
end
```

---

Define `generate_gradient` function which inserts `@x...` in your text:

```
local unpack, tonumber = table.unpack or unpack, tonumber

local function convert_color_to_table(rrggbb)
   if type(rrggbb) == "string" then
      local r, g, b = rrggbb:match"(%x%x)(%x%x)(%x%x)"
      return {tonumber(r, 16), tonumber(g, 16), tonumber(b, 16)}
   else
      return rrggbb
   end
end

local function round(x)
   return floor(x + 0.5)
end

local function generate_gradient(text, first_color, last_color)
   local r, g, b = unpack(convert_color_to_table(first_color))
   local dr, dg, db = unpack(convert_color_to_table(last_color))
   local char_pattern = "[^\128-\191][\128-\191]*"
   local n = max(1, select(2, text:gsub(char_pattern, "")) - 1)
   dr, dg, db = (dr - r)/n, (dg - g)/n, (db - b)/n
   local result = ""
   for c in text:gmatch(char_pattern) do
      result = result..("@x%03d"):format(nearest_term256_color_index(
         round(r), round(g), round(b)))..c
      r, g, b = r + dr, g + dg, b + db
   end
   return result
end
```

---

Test it inside terminal:

```
local function print_with_colors(str)
   print(
      str:gsub("@x(%d%d%d)",
         function(color_idx)
            return "\27[38;5;"..color_idx.."m"
         end)
      .."\27[0m"
   )
end

local str = "Gradient"
local blue, red = {0, 0, 255}, "#FF0000"
str = generate_gradient(str, blue, red)  -- gradient from blue to red
print(str)
print_with_colors(str)
```

`rainbow()` is not a gradient, it would be a chain of several gradients.

Comment: This is simply amazing. Thank you for the work you put into this, Egor. You have yet to fail to amaze me.

Answer (score 0):

I am done with this. Just using ANSI 256 color escape code pattern.

-- ref ANSI 256 color = https://robotmoon.com/256-colors/
str = '\27[38;5;34mG\27[38;5;35mr\27[38;5;36ma\27[38;5;37md\27[38;5;38mi\27[38;5;39me\27[38;5;50mn\27[38;5;51mt\27'

```
if f then f.Destroy() end
f=createForm()
pb=createPaintBox(f)
pb.Canvas.Font.Size=52
pb.Align='alClient'

local rect={}
rect.Left=0
rect.Top=0
rect.Right=pb.Width
rect.Bottom=pb.Height

pb.Repaint()
pb.Canvas.Font.Style='fsBold'
pb.Canvas.Font.Name='Trebuchet MS'
pb.Canvas.Font.Color = 0
pb.Canvas.textRect(rect,16,54,'Gradient')
pb.Canvas.textRect(rect,12,50,str)
```

Thank you @Egor Skriptunoff for the inspirited.[image]